# GlazedList sorted list sort order based on table's comparatorProperty

Tags: sorting, tableview, glazedlists

Before working with GlazedList, I was able to bind a sorted list to the table comparator property as shown

```
sortedList.comparatorProperty().bind(table.comparatorProperty());
```

But due to certain features of glazed list I've decided to try using glazed list instead. Problem now is how do I get my sorted list to sort based on what is my table's sort settings(the sort feature when clicking on the header).

I'm using javafx TableView.